# Kafka Connect : How to Cast nested property using kafka connect transfor?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have Kafka message and I am using Kafka Connect sink connector to move the message to s3. Tha message has 2 float fields `amount` and `total_amount`.

```
{
  "elements": [
    {
      "quantity": 4,
      "amount": {
        "bytes": "\u0004,\u001d€"
      },
    }
  ],
  "total_amount": {
    "bytes": "\u0004,\u001d€"
  }
}
```

I am using the Cast transformer to convert the fields `amount` and `total_amount`.

```
"transforms": "Cast",
"transforms.Cast.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.Cast$Value",
"transforms.Cast.spec": amount:float64, total_amount:float64"
```

Now, the issue is, above the transformer is converting only `total_amount` and not converting the `amount` because `amount` is nested inside `elements`. according to the Kafka connect [Cast](https://github.com/a0x8o/kafka/blob/64a6f2630428f5e1d431ccfbe738feaec829512d/connect/transforms/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/transforms/Cast.java#L55) class, it is in `TODO` to access the nested element which is preety weired to me. do you have any idea or workaround how to resolve the issue?

Comment: btw, the link you have is not the real Kafka source code repo, but yes, _simple_ message transforms are very simple; no nested traversals are done, and the alternative would be Kafka Streams/KSQL